# Example to construct a simple asymetric RSA key pair

Tags: math, cryptography

Im trying to understand the maths in a RSA asymetric keys generation. I founded few articles in the web, and my idea is not very clear, so i came here with the hope to finally be able to complete an example.
I understand very well maths, but im a bit confused with the steps so i will go step by step until I understand.

I will try this example with numbers lower than 16[0..15] (4bits)
To encrypt/decript the message: "hello world"

**Step 1: Select 2 randomly prime numbers**

P= 11
Q= 5

**Step 2: Calculate H [(P-1)*(Q-1)]**

H = (11-1) * (5-1) = 10* 4= 40

**Step 3: Select a random prime number lower than H (E) (I believe coprimes of H also works for E)**

E = 7

And now?

Answer (score 5):

We can continue from step 2:

**Step 3)** Select `E` such that `Greatest Common Divisor(H,E)=1` and `(1 < E < H)`

In your example we have `gcd(40,?)=1 and 1<?<40` --> 7 satisfies this, so we choose E=7

**Step 4)** Compute `d` such that `(dE) mod H =1` and `d<H`

In the example we have (d*7) mod 40=1 and d< 40 so we get d= 23

**Step 5)** public key is `{E,n}` and private key is `{d,n}` in which `n = P * Q`.
In the example we have the public key={7,55} and the private key={23,55}

**Step 6)** Compute `C= M^E(mod n)` for encrypting in which `M` is the numerical representation of the message we want to encrypt.

In the example, we have to interpret M="hello world" as a number. Here, I assume it is equal to 39 for keeping it simple (this number should be less than `n`). You can refer to [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/how-do-ciphers-change-plaintext-into-numeric-digits-for-computing) to know more about how to encode a text to a numeric value.

C= 39 ^7 mod 55 = 19 (encrypted value of M)

**Step 7)** Compute `M= C^d(mod n)` for decrypting 19

In the example, we have M=19^23 mod 55 = 39 (the Message which should be decoded to "hello world").

Comment: I did not know what you explain on step 5: each key have 2 numbers! And i neither know that M must be lower than n.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PedroJoseOteroRodriguez yep the keys for RSA are really two numbers, an exponent and a modulus. Also, regarding M lower than N, the way we usually work around this is to use symmetric cipher like AES or ChaCha to encrypt M, then encrypt symmetric key with RSA (symmetric key is always less than N for secure RSA).